# Uncaught DOMException: Blocked a frame with origin "xxxx" from accessing a cross-origin frame

Tags: html, nginx

this problem is really bugging me.

I have a cdn.xxx.com which is hosting a page (index.html) and I am loading it in page.xxx.com and I see this error:

Uncaught DOMException: Blocked a frame with origin "cdn.xxx.com" from accessing a cross-origin frame.

I added

```
add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' * always;
```

to my nginx.conf, but it is still showing the error. What am I missing?

Comment: check the ```X-Frame-Options``` header. it can cause issue while loading another url in iframe.

Comment: @AmitKumar iframe is being loaded. thats not the problem.

Comment: so when are you getting this error?